# yacc shift/reduce in parser

Tags: parsing, bison, yacc

I am writing  a parser for a compiler in one homework and when I am running the command

```
$ bison --yacc -v --defines -o parser.c parser.y
parser.y: warning: 8 shift/reduce conflicts [-Wconflicts-sr]
$
```

Except of the if/else shift/reduce conflict which is expected I am taking in parser.output file  conflicts in the following states,

State 34

```
 35 term: lvalue . PLUSPLUS
 37     | lvalue . MINUSMINUS
 39 assignexpr: lvalue . ASSIGN expr
 40 primary: lvalue .
 49 member: lvalue . FULLSTOP IDENTIFIER
 50       | lvalue . LEFTSQUARE expr RIGHTSQUARE
 54 call: lvalue . callsuffix

ASSIGN      shift, and go to state 88
PLUSPLUS    shift, and go to state 89
MINUSMINUS  shift, and go to state 90
LEFTSQUARE  shift, and go to state 91
FULLSTOP    shift, and go to state 92
LEFTPAR     shift, and go to state 93

PLUSPLUS    [reduce using rule 40 (primary)]
MINUSMINUS  [reduce using rule 40 (primary)]
LEFTSQUARE  [reduce using rule 40 (primary)]
LEFTPAR     [reduce using rule 40 (primary)]
$default    reduce using rule 40 (primary)

callsuffix  go to state 94
normcall    go to state 95
methodcall  go to state 96
```

State 36

```
 41 primary: call .
 51 member: call . FULLSTOP IDENTIFIER
 52       | call . LEFTSQUARE expr RIGHTSQUARE
 53 call: call . LEFTPAR elist RIGHTPAR

LEFTSQUARE  shift, and go to state 97
FULLSTOP    shift, and go to state 98
LEFTPAR     shift, and go to state 99

LEFTSQUARE  [reduce using rule 41 (primary)]
LEFTPAR     [reduce using rule 41 (primary)]
$default    reduce using rule 41 (primary)
```

State 52

```
 16 expr: expr . PLUS expr
 17     | expr . MINUS expr
 18     | expr . MUL expr
 19     | expr . DIV expr
 20     | expr . MOD expr
 21     | expr . GREATER expr
 22     | expr . GREATER_EQUAL expr
 23     | expr . LESS expr
 24     | expr . LESS_EQUAL expr
 25     | expr . EQUAL expr
 26     | expr . NOTEQUAL expr
 27     | expr . AND expr
 28     | expr . OR expr
 95 returnstmt: RETURN expr .

PLUS           shift, and go to state 74
MINUS          shift, and go to state 75
MUL            shift, and go to state 76
DIV            shift, and go to state 77
MOD            shift, and go to state 78
EQUAL          shift, and go to state 79
NOTEQUAL       shift, and go to state 80
OR             shift, and go to state 81
AND            shift, and go to state 82
GREATER        shift, and go to state 83
LESS           shift, and go to state 84
GREATER_EQUAL  shift, and go to state 85
LESS_EQUAL     shift, and go to state 86

MINUS     [reduce using rule 95 (returnstmt)]
$default  reduce using rule 95 (returnstmt)
```

Any idea how to solve it?

Answer (score 2):

Its difficult to say what the problem is as you don't show your full grammar.  Often times conflicts are due to other rules in the grammar (not the rules shown in the states with the conflict) due to the context, or how the rules are combined.

- state 34/36:
  It looks like you have some sort of circular ambiguity between the rules for `primary`, `lvalue`, and `call`.   What are these (full) rules?  How do expect to know the difference between an lvalue and a primary?
- state 52:  Here it looks like an ambiguity between a `returnstmt` and a following expression that begins with a `MINUS`.  It looks like you do not have a statement terminator/separator?

These all might be the same underlying problem -- the parser can't figure out where one statement ends and the next begins...